# How do I resolve Mixed Content Insecure Image in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, web-application, alternate-access-mapping

I created the following web applications:

1. https://webapp
2. http://mysite

UPSA My Site host is http://mysite

I created an employee directory which shows profile pictures as broken in Chrome (v83).

Chrome developer tools show the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but
> requested an insecure image ''. This content should also be
> served over HTTPS.

I created AAM of Internal url: https://mysite - zone: default - Public URL for Zone: http://mysite and added a binding to mysite in IIS as https://mysite (http://mysite still exists).

I also added mysite to allow insecure content in Chrome but images are still broken.

How would I fix this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new Web Application for My Sites - https://mysite, updated bindings, added SSL cert, created My Site Host Site Collection, updated UPSA and ran a script to import profile pics from AD to https://mysite.